# libc segfault when running cron

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I am trying to submit the job using drqueue's sendjob tool. When doing this from the terminal it works just fine. However, when doing this from cron, I get segmentation fault at libc (2.11.3-4). I tried using strace and I found that when running from cron, it can't open tty. What would the workaround be or maybe there's something else?

Comment: if you run the command as `yourcommand </dev/null` do you get the same segfault?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running it *screen*.

From the screen help (-h):

```
-dmS name     Start as daemon: Screen session in detached mode.
```

So something like

```
screen -dmS some_session_name "/path/to/yourstuff_here"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try preceding the command in your crontab with:

```
bash --login -c <command>
```

This runs your command in a separate login shell with the same environment variables as a terminal session.